# Include pom.xml in Jar with gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I'm attempting to include a generated `pom.xml` in the `jar` that I'm creating with gradle.

So far, in my parent project, I have

```
subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                from(components.java)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in the sub-project I have:

```
tasks.build.dependsOn install

sourceSets {
    main {
        resources {
            srcDirs = [ "src/main/resources", "build/poms" ]
        }
    }
}
```

This will generate `./build/poms/pom-default.xml`, but it will not add it to the JAR.

Creating a dependency on an earlier phase than `build` creates circular dependencies (and I don't know whether this is the problem anyway).

Also, I'd like the `pom.xml` to show up inside `META-INF` with name `pom.xml` (not `pom-default.xml`), so this may not be the right approach anyway.

Somehow I'm thinking it can't be as complicated as this looks?

Comment: This seems over-complicated. It depends on what you are trying to do of course, but you can have module-B import module-A by adding: `dependencies { compile project(':moduleA') }` to the build.gradle file for module-B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to include the POM in your JAR by adding the following to your `subprojects` closure:

```
jar {
    into("META-INF/maven/${project.group}/${project.name}") {
        from generatePomFileForMavenPublication
        rename { it.replace('pom-default.xml', 'pom.xml') }
    }
}
```

If you already have a `jar` closure, you can add it there. This automatically creates a task dependency on the *generatePomFileForMavenPublication* task, so that the POM file is there when the JAR is created.
The `sourceSets` part from your question would not be required for this.

(Side note: It would not be strictly necessary to do this at all, because the Maven publish process will publish the POM as an individual artifact anyway.)

Comment: This is where this whole gradle thing is incredibly baffling to me. Can I ask some follow-up questions? 1) Where in the docs would I start reading to find the breadcrumbs of info to eventually get to this answer myself? 2) pom-default.xml is in a very different directory: how does it find that? 3) if I am looking for the docs for each one of the nouns in your answer, how do I go about that? E.g. where does "rename" and "it" and "into" come from?

Comment: I'll try. The JAR is created by the [Jar](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/bundling/Jar.html) task, which has an [into()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar.html#org.gradle.jvm.tasks.Jar:into(java.lang.Object)) method because it's also a [CopySpec](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.3/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html). `rename` is also a method of the Jar task. `it` is Groovy syntax and refers to the current object of an iterator. Taking files `from` a task refers to the other task's declared outputs.

Comment: @JohannesErnst What I found helpful when diving into Gradle, is to setup a modern IDE (i.e. IntelliJ) which allows me to click into all these strange methods (into, rename, it) and get the developers documentation in the (open) source code.

Comment: Note that to be able to 'mvn install-file' the jar, I had to place the pom.xml in a META-INF subfolder like `"META-INF/maven/${project.group}/${project.name}"`.

Comment: Good point, this makes the example even better for practical use. @Alex