# From gradle, generate build and runtime dependencies into pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, gradle

Maven file excerpt:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':something:com.example.util')
    runtime project(':something:com.example.util')
}

apply plugin: 'maven'

task writeNewPom() {
    doLast {
        pom {
            project {
            }
        }.writeTo("$buildDir/resources/main/META-INF/maven/${project.group}/${project.name}/pom.xml")
    }
}

tasks.jar.dependsOn writeNewPom
```

I would expect that the generated `pom.xml` has dependencies with scopes `compile` and `runtime`, but I'm only getting the `compile` scope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>something</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.example.foo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>something</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.example.util</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

How do I get both scopes? Or, if I can't, how can I get the `runtime` scope which is more important for my use case?

Comment: I cannot really read Gradle, but in Maven, having more than one scope for a giving dependency is not possible (i.e. two `<dependency>` entries with different scopes for the same artifact make no sense).

Comment: How do you express that you need B.jar to compile the stuff that goes into A.jar, and that you have no hope to run A.jar without also having B.jar? (Or should the definition of "compile" also imply "runtime"?)

Comment: `compile` includes `runtime`. `compile` scope artifacts are available for compilation, test and at runtime.

Comment: Since both dependencies are the same, it might already be working?

Comment: Actually, it's the other way around: `runtime` includes `compile`. Nice graphic on this and explanations in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations) (scroll down a little for the illustration).

Comment: @barfuin: For maven, my explanation is correct.

Comment: Consider using the [maven-publish](https://docs.gradle.org/6.0/userguide/publishing_maven.html) plugin instead of `maven` (which has been deprecated for a long time). Then call `./gradlew generatePomFileForMavenJavaPublication`, which should give you the right POM in *build/publications/mavenJava/pom-default.xml*.

Comment: @barfuin: I tried that first, but I want the POM 1) inside the JAR, and 2) as a sibling in ~/.m2. So far I have failed accomplishing both using either approach, but the above one has gotten me a bit further :-(

Comment: Well you've solved [item 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58665551/1005481).  What do you mean by `sibling in ~/.m2`? Can you expand the question to clarify?

Comment: If I look into my `~/.m2`, many (all?) of `.../a/b/c/d.jar` also have a sibling `.../a/b/c/d.pom` and I'd like to do the same thing.

Comment: Okay. The maven-publish plugin would do all of this for you out of the box ... (and more, actually; it's not easy to reinvent the wheel correctly here)